# Upvote/Downvote system within Swift via Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I've looked over hours of code and notes and I'm struggling to find any documentation that would help me with upvoting and downvoting an object in a swift app with firebase.

I have a gallery of photos and I'm looking to add an instagram style upvote to images. The user has already logged with firebase auth so I have their user ID.

I'm just struggling to figure the method and what rules need to be set in firebase.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I will describe how I implemented such a feature in social networking app [Impether](https://itunes.apple.com/nz/app/impether/id1084468692?mt=8) using `Swift` and `Firebase`.

Since upvoting and downvoting is analogous, I will describe upvoting only.

**The general idea is to store a upvotes counter directly in the node corresponding to an image data the counter is related to and update the counter value using transactional writes in order to avoid inconsistencies in the data.**

For example, let's assume that you store a single image data at path `/images/$imageId/`, where `$imageId` is an unique id used to identify a particular image - it can be generated for example by a function [childByAutoId](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/Firebase.html#//api/name/childByAutoId) included in Firebase for iOS. Then an object corresponding to a single photo at that node looks like:

```
$imageId: {
   'url': 'http://static.example.com/images/$imageId.jpg',
   'caption': 'Some caption',
   'author_username': 'foobarbaz'
}
```

What we want to do is to add an upvote counter to this node, so it becomes:

```
$imageId: {
   'url': 'http://static.example.com/images/$imageId.jpg',
   'caption': 'Some caption',
   'author_username': 'foobarbaz',
   'upvotes': 12,
}
```

When you are creating a new image (probably when an user uploads it), then you may want to initialize the upvote counter value with `0` or some other constant depending on what are you want to achieve.

When it comes to updating a particular upvotes counter, you want to use transactions in order to avoid inconsistencies in its value (this can occur when multiple clients want to update a counter at the same time).

Fortunately, handling transactional writes in `Firebase` and `Swift` is super easy:

```
func upvote(imageId: String,
            success successBlock: (Int) -> Void,
            error errorBlock: () -> Void) {

    let ref = Firebase(url: "https://YOUR-FIREBASE-URL.firebaseio.com/images")
        .childByAppendingPath(imageId)
        .childByAppendingPath("upvotes")

    ref.runTransactionBlock({
        (currentData: FMutableData!) in

        //value of the counter before an update
        var value = currentData.value as? Int

        //checking for nil data is very important when using
        //transactional writes
        if value == nil {
            value = 0
        }

        //actual update
        currentData.value = value! + 1
        return FTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
        }, andCompletionBlock: {
            error, commited, snap in

            //if the transaction was commited, i.e. the data
            //under snap variable has the value of the counter after
            //updates are done
            if commited {
                let upvotes = snap.value as! Int
                //call success callback function if you want
                successBlock(upvotes)
            } else {
                //call error callback function if you want
                errorBlock()
            }
    })
}
```

The above snipped is actually almost exactly the code we use in production. I hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thank you ! Just to be exhaustive : now with Firebase SDK update, FMutableData becomes FIRMutableData and FTransactionResult becomes FIRTransactionResult

Comment: There is no solution for case when the user has been already liked. And it's not only changing + to -. You should store the userID and compare with current userID and this is much more complex.

Comment: This method works but this also means the same user can upvote multiple times. There isn’t anything in place to stop it because like @NikKov said, there needs to be a way to compare the uid of the user who already upvoted and the current user who is about to upvote.

Answer (score 3):

I was very surprised, but [this code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) from original docs works like a charm. There is one disadvantage with it: the json grows pretty big if there are a lot of likes.

```
FirebaseService.shared.databaseReference
            .child("items")
            .child(itemID!)
            .runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in
                if var item =  currentData.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                let uid = SharedUser.current!.id

                var usersLikedIdsArray = item["liked_who"] as? [String : Bool] ?? [:]
                var likesCount = item["likes"] as? Int ?? 0

                    if usersLikedIdsArray[uid] == nil  {
                        likesCount += 1
                        usersLikedIdsArray[uid] = true
                        self.setImage(self.activeImage!, for: .normal)
                        self.updateClosure?(true)
                    } else {
                        likesCount -= 1
                        usersLikedIdsArray.removeValue(forKey: uid)
                        self.setImage(self.unactiveImage!, for: .normal)
                        self.updateClosure?(false)
                    }

                item["liked_who"] = usersLikedIdsArray as AnyObject?
                item["likes"] = likesCount as AnyObject?

                currentData.value = item

                return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
            }
            return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
            if let error = error {
                self.owner?.show(error: error)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a Swift fella myself (pun!) but I think [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071022/firebase-how-to-check-transaction-success-or-fail) has most of your answers.

Then you would simply use a couple of if statements to return the correct value from the transaction based on whether you want to up vote or down vote.