# Building user database model in Firebase

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, backend

so I already finished all of the actual app for this. I just need to setup the backend. I figured Firebase was the best solution since Parse is no longer a thing. What I wanted was:

Users with profiles - These profiles can be viewed by added friends but only edited (written) to by the actual profile owner.

---

So I read through the Firebase Docs and still cannot really figure out how to do this. They only have 1 Swift application example that does not do anything similar and the one Obj C twitter one, will not even build. All of their docs still have println for Swift which just makes me think it is not updated frequently.

---

Does anyone have any good examples / tutorials of this? I keep trying to search for things but nothing is as similar enough to what I want. I am more looking on how to setup the db for each user and access it rather actually using Firebase in Swift.

Comment: I wrote the whole social app using Swift + Firebase. I think that you have to be more precise in describing what you want to achieve. Take a look at my app (https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/impether/id1084468692) and let me know if this is something that you're searching for, and with what do you have problems. Then I'll write a complete answer with code snippets we use in production, so it can be some kind of documentation about what you want to achieve :)

Comment: Hey! I downloaded and tried it out. Looks great! You have multiple users, who have their own profiles, that can only be written to by them, but viewed by friends. That is exactly what I am looking to do. I would greatly appreciate it if you write the answer. @pkacprzak

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment to your question, this answer is based on what we do in a real social app [Impether](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/impether/id1084468692) using `Swift` + `Firebase`.

## Data structure

Let's assume that you want to store the following information for a single user:

- **email**
- **username**
- **name**
- **followers** - number of people who follow a particular user
- **following** - number of people who a particular user follows
- **avatar_url** - url of their avatar
- **bio** - some additional text

Since in Firebase everything is stored a JSON objects, you can store the above structure under node with path like `users/$userId`, where `$userId` is Firebase User UID which is created for each registered user if you use simple email/password Firebase authorization.

Firebase email/password authorization is described in their docs:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html
https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/login/password.html

Notice that there are both Obj-C and Swift snippets. I find Firebase documentation really great as it helped me a lot when I was building our app.

For the purpose of this answer let's assume that we have user with username `jack` and Firebase User UID equal to `jack_uid` (in reality this will be a string generated by Firebase).

Then an example data for this user will be store under a path `users/jack_uid` and can look like this:

```
{
  "email" : "jack@example.com",
  "username" : "jack",
  "name" : "Jack",
  "followers" : 8,
  "following" : 11,
  "avatar_url" : "http://yourstoragesystem.com/avatars/jack.jpg",
  "bio" : "Blogger, YouTuber",
}
```

Firebase email/password authorization works really well, but let's be honest, if user wants to sign in into the app, it's a lot better for him to use his username than his email he gave while he registering his account.

In order to do that, we decided to store a mapping from usernames to user ids. The idea is that if user inputs his username and password in a login form, we use that mapping to retrieve his user id and then we try to sign him in using his user id and provided password.

The mapping can be stored for example under a path `username_to_uid` and looks like this:

```
{ 
   "sample_username_1": "firebase_generated_userid_1",
   "sample_username_2": "firebase_generated_userid_2",
   ...
   "jack": "jack_uid",
   "sample_username_123": "firebase_generated_userid_123"
}
```

Then creating a profile may looks like this and it's done as soon as registration of a new account was successful (this snippet is very close to the exact code we use in the production):

```
func createProfile(uid: String, email: String,
                   username: String, avatarUrl: String,
                   successBlock: () -> Void, errorBlock: () -> Void) {
   
    //path to user data node
    let userDataPath = "/users/\(uid)"
    
    //path to user's username to uid mapping
    let usernameToUidDataPath = "/username_to_uid/\(username)"
    
    //you want to have JSON object representing user data
    //and we do use our User Swift structures to do that
    //but you can just create a raw JSON object here.
    //name, avatarUrl, bio, followers and following are
    //initialized with default values
    let user = User(uid: uid, username: username, name: "",
                    avatarUrl: avatarUrl, bio: "",
                    followers: 0, following: 0)
    
    //this produces a JSON object from User instance
    var userData = user.serialize()
    //we add email to JSON data, because we don't store
    //it directly in our objects
    userData["email"] = email
    
    //we use fanoutObject to update both user data
    //and username to uid mapping at the same time
    //this is very convinient, because either both
    //write are successful or in case of any error,
    //nothing is written, so you avoid inconsistencies
    //in you database. You can read more about that technique
    //here: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-07-how-to-keep-your-data-consistent.html
    
    var fanoutObject = [String:AnyObject]()
    fanoutObject[userDataPath] = userData
    fanoutObject[usernameToUidDataPath] = uid
    
    let ref = Firebase(url: "https://YOUR-FIREBASE-URL.firebaseio.com/images")
    ref.updateChildValues(fanoutObject, withCompletionBlock: {
        err, snap in
        if err == nil {
            //call success call back if there were no errors
            successBlock()
        } else {
            //handle error here
            errorBlock()
        }
    })
}
```

In addition to this you possibly want to store for each user a list of his followers and a separate list of users he follows. This can be done just by storing user ids at a path like `followers/jack_uid`, for example it can look like this:

```
{
   "firebase_generated_userid_4": true,
   "firebase_generated_userid_14": true
}
```

This is the way we store sets of values in our app. It very convenient, because it is really user to update it and check if some value is there.

In order to count the number of followers, we put this counter into user's data directly. This makes reading the counter very efficient. However, updating this counter requires using transactional writes and the idea is almost exactly the same as in my answer here: [Upvote/Downvote system within Swift via Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061536/upvote-downvote-system-within-swift-via-firebase)

## Read/write permissions

A part of your question is how to handle permissions to data you store. The good news is that Firebase is exceptionally good here. If you go to  your Firebase dashboard there is a tab named `Security&Rules` and this is the place where you control permissions to your data.

What's great about Firebase rules is that they are declarative, which makes them very easy to use and maintain. However, writing rules in pure JSON is not the best idea since it's quite hard to control them when you want to combine some atomic rules into a bigger rule or your app simple grows and there are more and more different data you store in your Firebase database. Fortunately, Firebase team wrote Bolt, which is a language in which you can write all rules you need very easily.

First of all I recommend to read Firebase docs about Security, especially how does permission to a node influences permission for its children. Then, you can take a look at Bolt here:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/bolt/guide.html
https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-11-09-introducing-the-bolt-compiler.html
https://github.com/firebase/bolt/blob/master/docs/guide.md

For example, we use rules for managing users data similar to this:

```
//global helpers
isCurrentUser(userId) {
    auth != null && auth.uid == userId;
}

isLogged() {
    auth != null;
}

//custom types, you can extend them
//if you want to
type UserId extends String;
type Username extends String;
type AvatarUrl extends String;
type Email extends String;

type User {
    avatar_url: AvatarUrl,
    bio: String,
    email: Email,
    followers: Number,
    following: Number,
    name: String,
    username: Username,
}

//user data rules
path /users/{$userId} is User {
    write() { isCurrentUser($userId) }
    read() { isLogged() }
}

//user's followers rules
//rules for users a particular
//user follows are similar
path /followers/{$userId} {
    read() { isLogged() }
}

path /followers/{$userId}/{$followerId} is Boolean {
    create() { isCurrentUser($followerId) && this == true }
    delete() { isCurrentUser($followerId) }
}

//username to uid rules
path /username_to_uid {
    read() { true }
}

path /username_to_uid/{$username} is UserId {
    create() { isCurrentUser(this) }
}
```

The bottom line is that you write rules you want using `Bolt`, then you compile them into JSON using Bolt compiler and then you deploy them into your Firebase, using command line tools or by pasting them into dashboard, but command line is way more efficient. A nice additional feature is that you can test your rules by using tools in `Simulator` tab in your dashboard.

## Summary

For me Firebase is a great tool for implementing a system you want. However, I recommend to start with simple features and learn how to use Firebase in the first place. Implementing social app with functionality like for example Instagram is quite a big challenge, especially if you want to do it right :) It's very tempting to put all functionality there very quickly and Firebase makes it relatively easy to do, but I recommend to be patient here.

In addition, take your time and invest in writing tools. For example, we have two separated Firebase databases, one for production and second for testing, which is really important if you want to write unit and UI tests efficiently.

Also, I recommend building permission rules from the beginning. Adding them later may be tempting, but also quite overwhelming.

Last but not least, follow Firebase blog. They post regularly and you can be up to date with their latest features and updates - this is how I learnt how to use concurrent writes using fanout technique.

Comment: @pkacprxak Can you also show the struct you have? Your answer is awesome btw, I learned so much.

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp sure, which one do you want to see? Btw your previous comment (deleted somehow) landed on Twitter and it seems Joel Spolsky liked it

Comment: Yeah.. Somebody didn't liked my previously profound comment which was written from heart :) 
But I mean the User `Struct`. And what do you think are the advantages over some SQL doing such a project?

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp User struct is very straightforward. It is used just to pass public user data, so its instance is created from all fields in user type except email (because this field works like a private one and can be read and update only by its owner). No magic is used there. Feel free to ask if you have any specific questions.